# How to create a NSAutoreleasePool without Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macos

I have  multiplatform game written in C++. In the mac version, even though I do not have any obj-c code, one of the libraries I use seems to be auto-releasing stuff, and I get memory leaks for that, since I did not create a NSAutoreleasePool.

What I want is to be able to create (and destroy) a NSAutoreleasePool without using obj-c code, so I don't need to create a .m file, and change my build scripts just for that. Is that possible? How can that be done?

OBS: Tagged C and C++, because a solution in any of those languages will do.

Comment: Is your issue writing any objective-c code at all? Or having .m files in your project when you only want .c/.cpp?

Comment: Note that while @abarnert's code is a workable solution, this indicates a bug in the library. No C or C++ function should call into ObjC code without generating an autorelease pool. If this is Apple code, you should open a radar at bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: @Sean I only want .c/.cpp files. I know I can exclude those files to the other platforms build, but I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: @RobNapier: +1. And if it's a third-party library, you should file a bug with the library vendor. Many third-party libraries (especially cross-platform ones) assume that any Mac app has a Cocoa run loop and an active NSAutoreleasePool, even if you only call the C/C++ interface, and that's clearly wrong. They may not be able or willing to fix it, but you should let them know.

Comment: @RobNapier: It's not an Apple library. I am using only the standard library and multiplatform libraries.

Comment: What do you mean "only the standard library and multiplatform libraries?" Something is creating an autoreleased ObjC object. That's either in your code, a thirdparty's code, or Apple's code. Check the stack trace. (Stick a symbolic breakpoint on `objc_autoreleaseNoPool`)

Comment: @RobNapier: The game uses the standard C/C++ library, OpenGL, OpenAL, libvorbis (for ogg), libFreetype2 (for fonts) and SDL. It's one of them, most likely SDL. I haven't used (directly at least, SDL may be using one of those for me) Cocoa or any Apple library.

Comment: Sure. The breakpoint on `objc_autoreleaseNoPool` should show you the culprit pretty quickly, though.

Comment: +1. Or run nm or otool on each static and dynamic library and find out statically.

Comment: What build system are you using that makes it so hard to exclude *.m or wrapper.m on non-Mac platforms? (I ask because I once dealt with a system that required tons of hackery to do that… but it turned out to be very easy to tell it to compile .m files as C instead of ObjC on non-Mac, and then I just made all my .m files start with #ifdef APPLE_CC…)

Comment: @abarnert: The main problem would be actualy include the *.m file on the Mac version, I am using CMake. My CMake script is already way more complex then I would like it to be, and I was trying to avoid one more hack.

Comment: Personally, I find CMake a lot easier to understand than objc-runtime. Most CMake projects I've done have a platform-specific directory for each platform, and a few lines in the CMake to pick the right directory to drop into (which you can copy from examples or existing open source projects). But on the other hand, sometimes it's kind of fun to play around with ObjC behind its back, so if you want to do it that way, go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid instantiating the Objective-C runtime—but apparently you've already got one of those.

If you want to interact with the runtime from C, you can us the Objective-C runtime APIs, as documented in [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048) and [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html).

The idea is something like this (untested):

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>
#include <objc/objc-runtime.h>
id allocAndInitAutoreleasePool() {
  Class NSAutoreleasePoolClass = objc_getClass("NSAutoreleasePool");
  id pool = class_createInstance(NSAutoreleasePoolClass, 0);
  return objc_msgSend(pool, "init");
}
void drainAutoreleasePool(id pool) {
  (void)objc_msgSend(pool, "drain");
}
```

If you want to call these functions from another file, of course you'll have to include objc/runtime.h there as well. Or, alternatively, you can cast the id to void* in the return from the allocAndInit function, and take a void* and cast back to id in the drain function. (You could also forward-declare struct objc_object and typedef struct objc_object *id, but I believe that's not actually guaranteed to be the right definition.)

You shouldn't have to pass -lobjc in your link command.

Needless to say, it's probably less work to just make your build scripts handle .m files.

Comment: You should be able to load the runtime files with pure C code (without requiring `-lobjc`). You can see an example of this here: https://github.com/rnapier/ios5ptl/blob/master/ch20/Runtime/MyMsgSend.c (I'm not recommending that you use `myMsgSend()`, it's a demonstration of something else. I'm just showing a compilable C file that shows this approach works.)

Comment: As a side-note, while `.m` files might be ok, I do not recommend that you work around this problem with `.mm` files except as very small wrappers. ObjC++ causes a lot of problems. It's fine as a little piece of glue, and that's a fine way to solve this problem (stick the call in a little `.mm` function with a pure C or C++ header and an @autorelease{} around the call). But keep your C++ pure and your ObjC pure.

Comment: @RobNapier: Thanks for the note on -lobjc. I'll update the answer.